# SQL how to get one order from a particular customer

Tags: sql

i have a ( customer ) table, 
and ( order ) table. 
what code can i write to list the details of **only one order from a particular customer**.
since i have customer_ID as a Foreign Key in order table

```
select * 
from order, customer
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`/`ON`.  I also removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: or call a customer name from your customer table and then call the order of that customer from order table using  `WHERE` equivalent to the customer name got from the customer table.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp  already have customer and order. Just need to add the `WHERE` to include the customer_ID

Comment: I highly recommend you to read any tutorial on SQL. This is absolute beginner stuff and covered in any tutorial.

Comment: You need to know which columns in the 2 tables can be used to form a join. We cannot know exactly what those columns are given the absence of any detail in this question, but the query will *look something like* this: `select order.id, customer.name from order join customer on order.customer_id = customer.id`

Comment: @Used_By_Already  so could it be like this ? Select  *
From order, customer
join customer.customer_id = order.customer_id;

Comment: **Yes that could be how the 2 tables join.** What you should have done in your question is tell us what the columns are in both tables. There is guidance on how to create a good question: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: customer columns are :
**CUSTMER_ID**,First name,Last name,ADDRESS,city,PHONE,E-MAIL,ENGINEER ID,DATE,DURATION,Visiting purpose. and order columns are: **ORDER ID**,DATE ISSUED,DEADLINE,HEADOFFICE ,DEALERS ID,CUSTMER ID,STATUS,MAKE VICHLE,TYPE OF VICHLE.

Comment: @Used_By_Already someone told me that i can't write the join statment without where statment is that right?

Comment: Not true I'm afraid. There is nothing magical about joins performed through a where clause that cannot be performed using good ANSI SQL join syntax.